# Differential equation with basic integration solution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I found this exercise in my teacher's notes.

> Let $U=\{(x,y)\mid x^2-y^2>0\}$ and $$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$$ Find all functions $f(x,y)$ such that $f\in \mathcal{C}^2(U)$ and $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y) - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)= g(x,y)$$

The exercise looks too advanced for a Calculus of several variables course. But, apparently it can be solved without sophisticated tools of Partial Differential Equations.

I will appreaciate some help or maybe a hint. I tried integrating to $x$ and $y$ twice, respectively... But it just look more hard.

Hints??

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't covered it, take a look at the method where you reduce the PDE to canonical form. It's something like, if your equation is (f is a function of x and y): $$af_{xx}+2bf_{xy}+cf_{yy}=g(x,y)$$ then you solve the quadratic so that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-b +-\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ then you set the integration constants as the change of variable, i.e. if you're quadratic formula ends up with +-4 (which I'm not saying it does for this question, you can figure that one out ;) ) you get $$\eta = y -4x$$ and $$\nu = y + 4x$$. You then plug in the change of variable for the partials in the obvious way and you reduce the partials part to canonical form. Do the change of variables for the g(x,y) and then integrate (it does become easier at this point). I solved your question doing this, just remember the assumption on x^2 - y^2 when doing the integral and that the integration constants are functions, and I also feel it's a fair assumption to assume these constant functions are integrable, which makes life easier.

I didn't give you the answer I got because you only wanted a hint, but lmk if you want to see what I got. Also, check yourself on Wiki or there are some lecture notes online (do a quick net search) to try to find the proof and check that my methodology is solid. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y) - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$$
FIRST :

One look for a particular solution $f_p(x,y)$

Since any particular solution is convenient, why not looking for a solution on the simplified form
$$f_p(x^2-y^2)=f_p(t)\quad\text{with}\quad t=x^2-y^2$$
$\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x}=2x\frac{d f_p}{d t} $

$\frac{\partial^2 f_p}{\partial x^2}=2\frac{d f_p}{d t}+4x^2\frac{d^2 f_p}{\partial t^2} $

$\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial y}=-2y\frac{d f_p}{d t} $

$\frac{\partial^2 f_p}{\partial y^2}=-2\frac{d f_p}{\partial t}+4y^2\frac{d^2 f_p}{d t^2}$

$$\left(2\frac{d f_p}{d t}+4x^2\frac{d^2 f_p}{d t^2} \right) - \left(-2\frac{d f_p}{d t}+4y^2\frac{d^2 f_p}{d t^2} \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$$

$$4\frac{d f_p}{d t}+4t\frac{d^2 f_p}{d t^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$$
This is a linear ODE easy to solve :
$$f_p(t)=\sqrt{t}+c_1\ln|t|+c_2$$
Since one look for only a particular solution (any one) why not keeping the simplest one :
$$f_p(t)=\sqrt{t}$$
$$f_p(x^2-y^2)=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$$
SECOND :

One look for the general solution $f_h(x,y)$ of the homogeneous PDE :
$$\frac{\partial^2 f_h}{\partial x^2}(x,y) - \frac{\partial^2 f_h}{\partial y^2}(x,y)=0$$
This is wellknown :
$$f_h(x,y)=F(x+y)+G(x-y)$$
where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions.

THIRD :

The solution of the inhomogeneous linear PDE is the sum of the solution of the homogeneous PDE and a particular solution
$\quad f(x,y)=f_h(x,y)+f_p(x,y)$

$$f(x,y)=F(x+y)+G(x-y)+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$$